# How can I send HTTP Request from JetBrains to Prometheus?

Tags: httprequest, prometheus, jetbrains-ide

For JetBrains IDE I am creating an `index.http` file.

[spec.md](https://github.com/JetBrains/http-request-in-editor-spec/blob/master/spec.md)

> The document describes the HTTP Request in Editor format designed to provide a simple way to create, execute, and store information about HTTP requests. The specification mostly repeats RFC 7230 with several extensions intended for easier requests composing and editing.

> The differences between RFC 7230 and the HTTP Request in Editor format are highlighted using a smaller font size, e.g.:
> This text highlights the differences between the base HTTP message protocol and the HTTP Request in Editor format.

### Example

```
### LIST request
### POST http://localhost:2142/list
POST http://localhost:2142/list
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "list": {
    "data": "data",
    "version": "1",
    "type": "type",
    "description": description"
  }
}
```

I want to send this request to Prometheus. But I don't know where to start looking into this issue.

This can be done ?
Are there any examples if possible?

I decided to ask because this format is very similar to the metrics for the pm2 module

```
# HELP pm2_cpu Process cpu usage
# TYPE pm2_cpu gauge
pm2_cpu{id="0",name="pm2-prom-module",instance="0",interpreter="node",node_version="19.4.0"} 0
pm2_cpu{id="1",name="pm2-metrics",instance="0",interpreter="node",node_version="19.4.0"} 0
pm2_cpu{id="2",name="pm2-datadog",instance="0",interpreter="node",node_version="19.4.0"} 0
pm2_cpu{id="3",name="welcomebook",instance="0",interpreter="node",node_version="19.4.0"} 0
pm2_cpu{id="4",name="welcomebook",instance="1",interpreter="node",node_version="19.4.0"} 0
pm2_cpu{id="5",name="welcomebook",instance="2",interpreter="node",node_version="19.4.0"} 0
```